# Cannot manage Docker containers ("Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?")

Tags: docker

I have restarted my Lubuntu 14.04 server, but now I cannot reach the services in the following Docker containers anymore:

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2ddfda3167dd        ugoarangino/atlassian-confluence   "/bin/sh -c '/opt/at   9 months ago        Up 7 days           0.0.0.0:8101->8090/tcp   confluence          
308f1807fffb        ugoarangino/atlassian-jira         "/bin/sh -c '/opt/at   9 months ago        Up 7 days           0.0.0.0:8100->8080/tcp   jira                
ee33f63ec8a8        postgres                           "/docker-entrypoint.   9 months ago        Up 7 days           5432/tcp                 postgres
```

First I thought I'd try to restart a container, but when I try to stop it, I get:

```
$ sudo docker stop 2ddfda3167dd
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/containers/2ddfda3167dd/stop?t=10: EOF. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
Error: failed to stop containers: [2ddfda3167dd]
```

I get similar errors for `docker restart`, etc.

Here's my version info:

```
$ sudo docker version
Client version: 1.7.0
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 0baf609
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.0
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 0baf609
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

I also double checked that Docker is running:

```
$ sudo start docker
start: Job is already running: docker
```

Maybe this has something to to with the fact that these containers are set to auto restart upon reboot? Or maybe because I updated all packages on my system, which might have brought in a new Docker version...?

Can anyone tell me where I go from here?

Comment: Putting the actual error message in the title, without quotes, confused me a bit. At first I thought it might have been an attempt at rephrasing / commenting on the question. Might just be me...

Answer (score 1):

The "EOF" part of the error message did feel like there is something wrong in some script. So I tried reverting form 1.7.0 back to 1.6.2 and... it worked!

So either it's a bug in 1.7.0 or I should have ran some kind of upgrade script...? Does anyone know?

Anyway... it works again. I'm happy.